# Access Forbidden on heroku while deploying laravel app

Tags: heroku, laravel-5, heroku-cli

I am trying to host a laravel application oh heroku. But i'm gettin the access forbidden message. I have created the Procfile and placed the following code

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

I have also placed the following code in my composer.json

```
 "php artisan clear-compiled",
 "php artisan optimize",
 "chmod -R 777 public/"
```

I also have checked if the htaccess file exist in public directory.
I'm still getting the error. Please help me with this some one

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Procfile is inside the root directory of your project (not inside `public/`), and that it contains `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public`

Comment: You may need to alter `Procfile`. Im also having difficulty loading my project on heroku